# Matrix inverse of block symmetric matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices

Provided that $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are $n\times n$ symmetric matrices, the matrix $\mathbf{C}$ is constructed by $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ with the form of
\begin{align}
\mathbf{C}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} &\cdots &\mathbf{B}\\
\mathbf{B} & \mathbf{A} &\cdots &\mathbf{B}\\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\\
\mathbf{B} & \mathbf{B} &\cdots &\mathbf{A}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Note that $\mathbf{C}$ is $mn\times mn$ matrix. Given the information above, do we get the expression of matrix inverse of $\mathbf{C}$. I guess that $\mathbf{C}^{-1}$ has the same structure as $\mathbf{C}$, but I can't get its expression.

Comment: Do $A$ and $B$ commute? If so, you can "pretend that $A$ and $B$ are one-dimensional matrices" and plug in $A$ and $B$ at the end, but if not this doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are two different symmetric matrices. The dimension $n>1$. Both $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ and $\mathbf{B}^{-1}$ exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach using the fact that $B^{-1}$ exists. Note that
$$
C = (I_m \otimes B)(I_m \otimes (B^{-1}A - I) + J_m \otimes I_n),
$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product, $I_k$ denotes the identity matrix of size $k$, and $J_m$ is the size $m$ matrix whose entries are all equal to $1$. We note that
$$
C^{-1} = (I_m \otimes (B^{-1}A - I) + J_m \otimes I_n)^{-1}(I_m \otimes B)^{-1}
\\ = 
(I_m \otimes M + J_m \otimes I_n)^{-1}(I_m \otimes B^{-1}),
$$
where $M = B^{-1}A - I$. Let $e \in \Bbb R^m$ denote the column-vector whose entries are all $1$; note that $J_m = ee^T$. If $M$ and $M + mI$ are invertible, then with the Woodbury matrix identity we can write
$$
\begin{align}
(I_m \otimes M + J_m \otimes I_n)^{-1} & = 
(I_m \otimes M + (e \otimes I_n)(e \otimes I_n)^T)^{-1}
\\ & = (I_m \otimes M)^{-1} - (I_m \otimes M)^{-1}(e \otimes I_n)(
\\ & \quad \qquad  I_{n} + (e \otimes I_n)^T(I_m \otimes M)^{-1}(e \otimes I_n)
\\ & \quad )^{-1}(e \otimes I_n)^T(I \otimes M)^{-1}
\\ & = (I_m \otimes M^{-1}) - (I_m \otimes M^{-1})(e \otimes I_n)
\\ & \quad \qquad  \cdot(I_{n} + (e^Te \otimes M^{-1}))^{-1}(e \otimes I_n)^T(I \otimes M^{-1})
\\ & = (I_m \otimes M^{-1}) - (e \otimes M^{-1})(I_{n} + m \cdot M^{-1})^{-1}(e^T \otimes M^{-1}).
\end{align}
$$
We can simplify this a bit further: note that the second term can be reduced as follows.
$$
(e \otimes M^{-1})(I_{n} + m \cdot M^{-1})^{-1}(e^T \otimes M^{-1}) = \\
(e \otimes M^{-1})M(M + m I_n)^{-1}(e^T \otimes M^{-1}) = \\
(e \otimes I_n)(M + mI_n)^{-1}(e^T \otimes M^{-1}) = \\
(e \otimes (M + mI_n)^{-1})(e^T \otimes M^{-1}) = \\
(ee^T) \otimes [(M + mI_n)^{-1}M^{-1}] = \\
J_m \otimes (M^2 + m\cdot M)^{-1}.
$$
Putting this all together, we get
$$
C^{-1} = 
(I_m \otimes M + J_m \otimes I_n)^{-1}(I_m \otimes B^{-1})\\
= (I_m \otimes M^{-1} - J_m \otimes (M^2 + m\cdot M)^{-1})(I_m \otimes B^{-1})
\\ = 
I_m \otimes (M^{-1}B^{-1}) - J_m \otimes ((M^2 + m\cdot M)^{-1}B^{-1})
\\ = 
I_m \otimes (A - B)^{-1} - J_m \otimes (B(B^{-1}A - I)^2 + m \cdot (A - B))^{-1}.
$$
Because this expression is in the form $I_m \otimes P + J_m \otimes Q$, we can see that $C^{-1}$ will indeed have the same block-structure as $C$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to construct the inverse of $C$. A simple counterexample is enough to demonstrate:

Let $$A=B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$ and $m=2$. Both $A$ and $B$ are invertible. Then
$$C
=
\begin{bmatrix}A & B\\B & A
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has pairs of identical rows and columns, and so has determinate $0$ (is degenerate) and cannot be inverted. Thus there is no general way to construct $C^{-1}$.

Comment: It is still perhaps worth wondering about the possibility of a condition given that the block matrix is invertible.

Comment: @Suzu this is like saying that "there is no general way to construct the inverse of a $2 \times 2$ matrix" because some $2 \times 2$ matrices fail to be invertible, but I would consider the formula
$$
\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}^{-1} = \frac 1{ad - bc} \pmatrix{d&-b\\-c&a}
$$
to be a construction of the inverse (which holds in all cases that the matrix is invertible).

Comment: The inverse doesn't exist if $A=B$, otherwise it should exist.

Comment: @Suzu Hirose Thank you for the answer.  Both $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are two different $n\times n$ matrices. In addition, both $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ and $\mathbf{B}^{-1}$ exist.

Comment: @piyush_sao That's not true. For example,
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}.
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann That's correct.